# based on column cell value how to extract specific no# of character from string using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Like Left formula we Used in Excel same as I want to extract no. of character from Policy no. column based on Insurer column like.....

if insurer is HDFC then Extract only 10 character form the sting and
if insurer is tata then Extract only 7 character form the sting.
and **if insurer other than HDFC & tata then leave it as blank.**

***also see hdfc insure comes with lot of different name.***

How I will achieve this in python

| Insurer | Policy no. | *Expected OutPut* |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hdfc | 4509242332 | 4509242332 |
| Tata | tatadigitNational | tatadig |
| Hdfc ergo | 09082323ab12sd | 09082323ab |
| HDFC | nolanheroman | nolanherom |
| Tata | 97543007356 | 9754300 |
| Tata | pqrsequence2o202 | pqrsequ |
| Tata | 987654321 | 9876543 |
| HDFC health ergo | nolanheroman | nolanherom |
| Digit | 1733choola |  |
| star | naahiHonaar |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) accessor per group with help of a dictionary:

```
num = {'hdfc': 10, 'tata': 7}

# identify insurer from first word (can be changed to another method)
group = df['Insurer'].str.extract('(\w+)', expand=False).str.lower()

df['Expected OutPut'] = (df.groupby(group)['Policy no.']
                           .transform(lambda g: g.str[:num[g.name]]
                                             if g.name in num else '')
                        )
```

output:

```
            Insurer         Policy no. Expected OutPut
0              Hdfc         4509242332      4509242332
1              Tata  tatadigitNational         tatadig
2         Hdfc ergo     09082323ab12sd      09082323ab
3              HDFC       nolanheroman      nolanherom
4              Tata        97543007356         9754300
5              Tata   pqrsequence2o202         pqrsequ
6              Tata          987654321         9876543
7  HDFC health ergo       nolanheroman      nolanherom
8             Digit         1733choola                
9              star        naahiHonaar
```

##### update: enforce a minimal length

```
num = {'hdfc': 10, 'tata': 7}

group = df['Insurer'].str.extract('(\w+)', expand=False).str.lower()

df['Expected OutPut'] = (df.groupby(group)['Policy no.']
                           .transform(lambda g: g.mask(g.str.len()<num[g.name], '')
                                                 .str[:num[g.name]]
                                             if g.name in num else '')
                        )
```

output:

```
            Insurer         Policy no. Expected OutPut
0              Hdfc         4509242332      4509242332
1              Tata  tatadigitNational         tatadig
2         Hdfc ergo     09082323ab12sd      09082323ab
3              HDFC             nolanh                   # example here
4              Tata        97543007356         9754300
5              Tata   pqrsequence2o202         pqrsequ
6              Tata          987654321         9876543
7  HDFC health ergo       nolanheroman      nolanherom
8             Digit         1733choola                
9              star        naahiHonaar
```

Answer (score 1):

Check Below Answer using **np.where**, Expected_Output_Answer is calculated column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['Expected_Output_Answer'] = np.where(df['Insurer'].str.contains('hdfc', case=False), 
                                 df['Policy no.'].str[:10],
                                 np.where(df['Insurer'].str.contains('tata', case=False),
                                 df['Policy no.'].str[:7],
                                 ""
                                 )
                                 )
df
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to create a helper function `clipper`. `m` contains  the number of characters to clip per row (assuming that the first 4 characters will be `hdfc`/`tata`/other), then the vectorized `clipper` function can be applied to `Policy no.` and `m`.

```py
import numpy as np

def clipper(string, stop):
    return string[:stop]

m = df.Insurer.str[:4].str.lower().map({"hdfc": 10, "tata": 7}).fillna(0).astype(int)
df["Expected OutPut"] = np.vectorize(clipper)(df["Policy no."], m)
```